# Why does this ConditionalExpression appear?

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I am new to *Mathematica*. Could anyone help explain why `ws > 0` appears in the solution? How to define symbolic variables' range? Thanks!

[image: ws>0 has been defined]

---

**EDIT to include code**

```
z = Exp[2 \[Pi] I \[Omega]/\[Omega]s];
stf = 1/(z - 1);
eq1 = Abs[stf] == 1;
Solve[{eq1, \[Omega]s > 0, \[Omega]s > 2 \[Omega], \[Omega] > 0}, {\[Omega]}]
```

> ```
> {{\[Omega] -> ConditionalExpression[\[Omega]s/6, \[Omega]s > 1]}}
> ```

[image]

Comment: looking at help for Solve, I do not see where it takes assumptions?  it takes domain thoughas third argument.  May be that is why? So for your example, try `Assuming[{ws > 0, ws > 2*w, w > 0}, Simplify@Solve[eq1, w]]` and this gives `w -> ws/6` and next time, please post plain text code.

Comment: @Nasser `Solve` can take an explicit `Assumptions` option or be aware of external assumptions [since version 12.2](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn122).

Comment: @MarcoB well, in this case, I can't explain it.

Comment: @MarcoB oh, the new assumptions to Solve added in 12.2 have to be in the form `Assumptions->` not as shown in the post. Hence this works `Solve[eq1, w, Assumptions -> {ws > 0, ws > 2*w, w > 0}]`. But  As written by OP, `Solve`  looks like it did not use them as Assumptions since not the correct syntax was used.

Comment: You're the one who provided the conditions. Solution says that w = ws/6 satisfies eq1, ws >0, ws > 2w, and w > 0 provided ws > 0.  That is exactly correct, mathematically speaking.

Comment: @Nasser Oh I see what you meant as assumptions! Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think the question is, since OP thought they told `Solve` that ws>0, then why did `Solve` return an answer along with it saying that `ws>0`. For them this looks like redundant. At least this is how I read it. The problem  is that `Solve` did not use `ws>0` as assumption, because it was not in correct syntax. They should have used `Assumptions->`

Comment: @Nasser Thank you. `Assuming[{ws > 0, ws > 2*w, w > 0}, Simplify@Solve[eq1, w]]` doesn't work, but I could `Simplify` the result with a assumption to eliminate `ConditionalExpression`.

Comment: @Ring  you must be using older version. I am using 12.3.1 on windows. It works there. Here is screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk7NO.png

Comment: `Reduce[{eq1, \[Omega]s > 0, \[Omega]s > 2 \[Omega], \[Omega] > 
   0}, {\[Omega]}]` results in `\[Omega]s > 0 && \[Omega] == \[Omega]s/6`.

Comment: @Nasser Yes you are right, my `$Verison` is 12.0.

Comment: @MarcoB I just upgrated to 12.3.1, `Solve[eq1, w, Assumptions -> {ws > 0, ws > 2*w, w > 0}]` works well, thank you!

Comment: @Nasser The code says what I said it does. If the OP means something else, which is something that often happens, they did not indicate it. It seems to me that my comment does "explain why `ws > 0` appears in the solution" quite clearly.

Comment: @Nasser (Also, I upvoted your first comment because it seemed a reasonable guess at the intention. But sometimes people actually do mean what they say, via code in this case, and I though someone should address that.)